# the set of all irrational numbers is homeomorphic to its one point deleted subset

Tags: general-topology

It is easy to prove that the set of all rational  numbers (since it is countable) is homeomorphic to its one point deleted subset.
But I could not prove the statement: the set of all irrational numbers is homeomorphic to its one point deleted subset

Comment: What is the topology of your space(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ denote the set of irrational numbers and $S' = S \setminus \{ x \}$ where $x \in S$. Both carry the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $(q_n)$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers such that $q_n \to x$ and $q_1 = M > 0$ and let $(p_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers such that $p_n \to x$ and $p_1 = -M < 0$.

Define a map $f : S \to S'$ by
$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
t & \lvert t \rvert > M \\
p_n + \dfrac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{-M/(n+1) + M/n}(t + M/n) & -M/n < t < -M/(n+1) \\
q_{n+1} + \dfrac{q_n  - q_{n+1}}{M/n -M/(n+1)}(t - M/(n+1)) & M/(n+1) < t < M/n
\end{cases}
$$
The idea is to map the open subsets $(-M/n, -M/(n+1)) \cap S$ resp. $(M/(n+1), M/n) \cap S$ of $S$ linearly onto the open subsets $(p_n,p_{n+1}) \cap S'$ resp. $(q_{n+1},q_n) \cap S'$ of $S'$.

It is easy to give a formal proof that $f$ is well-defined and continuous.

An inverse for $f$ can be defined similarly. Details are left to you.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem. (Cantor). Any two countably infinite dense linear orders without end-points are order-isomorphic. (see *Footnote).

So, given $r\in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q,$ there is a bijection $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$ \ $\{0\}$ such that $f:{\Bbb Q\cap (-\infty,r)}:\to \Bbb Q \cap (-\infty,0)$ and $f:{\Bbb Q \cap (r,\infty)}:\to  \Bbb Q \cap (0,\infty)$ are order-isomorphisms.

Now for $r\ne s\in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q,$ define $f(s)=\sup \{f(x):s>x\in \Bbb Q\}.$

Show that $f$ maps $(\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q)$ \ $\{r\}$ order-isomorphically onto $\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q.$ Since the order-induced topologies on these two sets do co-incide with their subspace topologies (as subspaces of $\Bbb R$), therefore they are homeomorphic.

*Footnote. A linear order $<$ on a set $S$ is dense iff there exists $c$ with $a<c<b $ whenever $a,b\in S$ with $a<b.$

Answer (score 0):

The following is a classical topological characterisation of the irrational numbers, due to Alexandroff and Urysohn, *Über nulldimensionale Punktmengen*, Math. Ann 98, 1928, 89-106:

> Suppose $X$ is a zero-dimensional, second countable, $T_3$ space that is Čech-complete. (We could state the previous as $X$ is a [zero-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) for short). Then if $X$ is nowhere compact (this means that if $K\subseteq X$ is compact then $\operatorname{int}(K)=\emptyset$) then $X$ is homeomorphic to the irrational numbers as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ (also denoted $\Bbb P$).

(A modern reference for this result is Kechris' book "Classical Descriptive Set Theory", but it's in many more).

It implies that $\mathbb{P}$ is homeomorphic to $\omega^\omega$ in the product topology, and to its own finite and countable powers and also that $\mathbb{P}\simeq \mathbb{P}\setminus \{x\}$ for any $x$ in $\mathbb{P}$: The "one-point deleted irrationals" is still zero-dimensional (this is an hereditary property), nowhere compact (this is an open-hereditary property), and Polish (as an open set is a $G_\delta$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is Polish), so homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}$. In fact, any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{P}$ is homeomorphic to the whole space (which it has in common with $\mathbb{Q}$ and the Cantor set (if we take a *clopen* subset of it, of course), and many other spaces.

Quite a few classic spaces have such "pithy" characterisations: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only countable metric space without isolated points and the Cantor set is the only compact zero-dimensional metric space without isolated points (all from around the same time as the above result on the irrationals). See [this chapter](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/miscellaneous/ency.pdf) from the Encyclopedia of General Topology for more info. They can be powerful tools.